# Wicket - Append Javascript (What is Better Practice?)

Tags: javascript, java, wicket

I have two panels in Wicket.

`ParentPanel` and
`ChildPanel`

**Scenario**

`ChildPanel` is a component of `ParentPanel`.
Every time a certain event is fired in the Parent panel, I want to prepend a certain javascript in the `ChildPanel`.

**Working Solution**

`ParentPanel.java`

```
public class ParentPanel extends Panel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4306746527837380863L;
    private final ChildPanel childPanel;

    public ParentPanel(String aId, IModel<AnnotatorState> aModel)
    {
        super(aId);
        model = aModel;

        // initially the Child panel is empty. passing empty model
        childPanel = new ChildPanel("child-container", Model.of());
        childPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(childPanel);
    }

    @OnEvent
    public void onClickText(RenderEvent aEvent)
    {
        LOG.trace("Event Fired");
        IPartialPageRequestHandler iPartialPageRequestHandler = aEvent.getRequestHandler();

        Integer someData = getSomeData();
        childPanel.setDefaultModel(Model.of(someData));

        //I am trying to add the child panel to the ajax target to ensure rerendering of child panel.
        iPartialPageRequestHandler.add(childPanel);
    }
}
```

`ChildPanel.java`

```
public class ChildPanel extends Panel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3849226240909011148L;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChildPanel.class);
    private IModel<Integer> model;

    public ChildPanel(String aId, IModel<Integer> aModel)
    {
        super(aId);
        model = (aModel);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse aResponse)
    {
        super.renderHead(aResponse);
        model = (IModel<Integer>) getDefaultModel();

        if (model == null)
            return;
        Integer someData = model.getObject();
        String someJavascript = createSomeJavascript(someData);

        log.debug("Rendering Updated UI with the JS: ", javascript);
        aResponse.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript(javascript));
    }
}
```

Apparently renderHead() is called every time the childPanel is added to the iPartialPageRequestHandler and it does my work that is to update the UI on every event fired in the `ParentPanel`.

**Problem**

However I have been told that this is not a good practice. Since in this case, the JS is added to renderHead(), then it ends up in the page source code - that gets cumbersome when sending (large) JSON data. A good place to attach the JS to the AJAX target needs to be found (maybe render() or probable better onRender() or onAfterRender()) only if its possible/doable in Wicket. Due to my limited knowledge, I am not able to guess how else I can implement the scenario. Any other (better or possible) solution is welcomes and appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: What you're currently doing is adding a HeaderItem (i.e. a snippet that gets placed in the `<head>`) on each render. If, what you want to do instead is to execute a certain piece of JS before/after adding the component but no more, then you should look at the methods `IPartialPageRequestHandler.prependJavaScript` and `IPartialPageRequestHandler.appendJavaScript`.

Comment: I have explored these methods. But I can only use them if I have an ajax target object. Which leads me to question, in which function should I prepend the javascript so that it is called everytime the child panel is added to the request handler. I try to implement the onRender or onAfterRender method but I am not able to get an ajaxTarget or iPartialPageRequestHandler which I can use to call the prependJavaScript method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I never mentioned AjaxRequestTarget. I'm referring to these methods: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/8.x/org/apache/wicket/core/request/handler/IPartialPageRequestHandler.html#prependJavaScript-java.lang.CharSequence- and https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/8.x/org/apache/wicket/core/request/handler/IPartialPageRequestHandler.html#appendJavaScript-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: Then again, I'm not sure if those exist in Wicket 1.5.x or 6.x (which you tagged), though they definitely exist in Wicket 7.x and 8.x

Comment: Yes these methods exist but can I access the IPartialPageRequestHandler object in onRender() so that I can call prependJavascript in that function?

Comment: I need to override a function in ChildPanel that is called every time it is rerendered from the ParentPanel. And also there should be a way to access the iPartialPageRequestHandler object so I can call prependJavaScript() on it.

I am only guessing that overriding a method like onRender() with iPartialPageRequestHandler would help me. But I am not sure if it exists. Also it can be done some other way than simply overriding a method.

Comment: Since ParentPanel already has a reference to ChildPanel, can't you solve this by simply introducing your own method in ChildPanel and calling that from the `onClickText` method?

Comment: If I do that, then refreshing the page will remove the javascript. The reason I am looking for a function like onRender() is to make sure it is executed also when the page is refreshed after the button click. You can say once the button is clicked and the JS(Example a javascript graph) appears in the ChildPanel UI then I want to persist it, even on the page refresh until the next button is clicked. On the next button, again I want to update the Javascript based on the click and change the UI. Again with refresh the UI(JavaScript) must persist.

Comment: I am keeping the data in the model of ChildPanel so on refresh it can be used to use the same javascript to render the same UI that was rendered on the very recent click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is that the `createSomeJavascript` creates a big chuck of code?

I would then refactor it so that  `createSomeJavascript` just calls a function that you add to the Component using a `JavaScriptResourceReference`. This way, only a small bit of Javascript ends up in the source.

For example, put your javascript in an external file like this:

```
private static final ResourceReference  JS_QM   = new JavaScriptResourceReference( ClientPanel.class, "question.mark.js" );


@Override
public void renderHead( Component component, IHeaderResponse response )
{
    super.renderHead( component, response );
    response.render( JavaScriptReferenceHeaderItem.forReference( JS_QM, "question-mark" ) );
    ...
}
```

Comment: How to add a javascript function to the component using `JavaScriptResourceReference`?

Comment: If I refactor my function in the way you suggested then I will still be passing a large chunk of data on the function call. It is a chart render function and it needs arrays of data to show as learning curve. Don't you think the problem will stay the same?

Comment: Ah (you can improve your question with this info :). If that is your problem, you could use a charting library that can fetch data dynamically (via ajax for example), and use, a `Behaviour` with a callback-url that will get you the data.  Just pass the callback url and let the JS fetch it's own data.

Comment: Maybe check this for inspiration: https://github.com/adessoAG/wicked-charts